# My microphone is not working

Tags: microphone, audio-jack

My alsa info: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=f940e25a16fa01f2a1c2f980562b2a97d4b97ee5
My k56cd asus laptop has a combo jack (both headphones and mic) so when i plug in my headphones (Razer Kraken pro neon which have only 1 jack) only the headphones work, the mic does not.

Answer (score 26):

- Install "Jack retasking for HDA Intel sound cards" with:

  ```
  sudo apt install alsa-tools-gui
  ```
- Open it with <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> or in terminal:

  ```
  hdajackretask
  ```
- Select the up-right checkbox "Show unconnected pins"
- In the not connected pins 0x18 and 0x19, select "override", and select "microphone".
  If, they don't have the microphone option, do this in 0x16 or 0x12
- Click "apply now" (bottom right) and "install boot override".
- install pavucontrol

  ```
  sudo apt install pavucontrol
  ```
- Open `pavucontrol`, go to Input devices (4th menu) and select "Microphone", instead of "Internal microphone" (if it appears "(unplugged)" see if the volume indicator moves while you speak, otherwise restart - it can still be "unplugged" but should work).

For dual-boot systems, turn off the machine after the last windows use.

Comment: used for Asus Vivobook and Ubuntu 22.04 and it worked

Answer (score 3):

The problem could be that the input devices are not set up correctly. You should try PulseAudio Volume Control to correctly set it up.

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Open it up:

```
pavucontrol
```

Go into the Input Devices tab and underneath your audio card select the correct mic from the drop down list.

However, if your issue occurs when you reboot with the jack still plugged in, it can sometimes be resolved by simply unplugging and plugging the jack back in once the computer fully starts back up.

Answer (score 1):

You could verify also with alsamixer. Open the terminal and type `alsamixer` and then look for the microphone settings in alsamixer.