# My microphone mic is not working

Tags: sound, alsa

My alsa info: http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=7e9f9a1f69861ac557a0697fb0dd528adace00d1

My Acer Aspire 3 laptop has a combo jack (both headphones and mic) so when i plug in my headphones (tried multiple headphones razer+other brands) only the headphones work, the mic does not.

i show similar post here [My microphone is not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897437/my-microphone-is-not-working) but when i try to reset jack it just gives error. see screenshot [image]

also after shutting down system applying settings hdajackretask pavucontrol shows following input devices but still no sound using headphone mic. [image]

I suspect i need to do other changes or some other issue with my settings also i am using ubuntu 22.04 so is there any other changes i need to make or some other pins apply based on my sound card ?

Comment: What happens if you test it booting from a live pendrive?

Comment: Check it's not muted using alsamixer; make sure the plug socket isn't dirty.

Answer (score 0):

First determine what handles your audio device - there are multiple ways - ALSA, Pulseaudio, Jack, Pipewire
even if you using tools for any of those and those are working it might mislead you - as all those audio framework can work directly with hardware or sit on top of another framework installed in parallel. To determine issue those two commands:

```
systemctl  | egrep  'alsa|pulse|jack|pipewire'
sudo ps aux  | egrep  'alsa|pulse|jack|pipewire'
```

Also it would be probably better to stop audio system at all using `systemctl` command, then do the modificaton and start audio system again. If you want this change to be permament you can use 'Boot override' option of the tool.

Regarding exact error you are getting you can try:
`lsof /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/reconfig` to determine what occupies the device. Also check if your `groups` output contains `audio` group

Comment: ALSA is not on the same group, check [this video](https://youtu.be/HxEXMHcwtlI)

Comment: Not sure what you exactly mean, but Alsa means both kernel driver and userspace component