# Ubuntu 22.04 Microphone doesn't recognised

Tags: drivers, microphone

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, and face with problem, microphone(3.5 Jack port) doesnt recognised. Laptop has only one port. I've tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897437/my-microphone-is-not-working/1163677#1163677) way, but it didn't help me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jqFw.png)

Comment: maybe you can upgrade to 23.04, when you plug in, a menu appears to select headset