# Ubuntu 22.04: Bluetooth disconnects right after it connects

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa

I have been struggling with this from quite some time.

When I double booted my laptop to Ubuntu 22.04. It worked fine. Today, I had a call and I remembered the Ubuntu doesn't work with Bluetooth Earphones as Mic out-of-the-box, so I followed the following
[My microphone is not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897437/my-microphone-is-not-working/1163677#1163677)

> Install "Jack retasking for HDA Intel sound cards" with:
>
> sudo apt install alsa-tools-gui Open it with ⊞ Win or in terminal:
>
> hdajackretask Select the up-right checkbox "Show unconnected pins"
>
> In the not connected pins 0x18 and 0x19, select "override", and select
> "microphone". If, they don't have the microphone option, do this in
> 0x16 or 0x12
>
> Click "apply now" (bottom right) and "install boot override".
>
> install pavucontrol
>
> sudo apt install pavucontrol Open pavucontrol, go to Input devices
> (4th menu) and select "Microphone", instead of "Internal microphone"
> (if it appears "(unplugged)" see if the volume indicator moves while
> you speak, otherwise restart - it can still be "unplugged" but should
> work).
>
> For dual-boot systems, turn off the machine after the last windows
> use.

This solution had worked for me for a different computer but it didn't for this.
I've been trying a lot of things but it just doesn't work.

I do get the following in syslog

```
Nov  9 20:26:54 kungf bluetoothd[527]: src/service.c:btd_service_connect() a2dp-sink profile connect failed for 04:CB:88:D0:F4:9A: Protocol not available
```