# My headphone on my Ubuntu is not working Asus gl503ge

Tags: sound, 22.04, asus, headphones, audio-jack

thank you in advance for any help. I've just installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS for work purposes. I installed it on a HDD disk that came with the computer, and everything works wonderfully. However, I've encountered a single issue: my headphones don't work on my Asus computer when I plug them into the Jack input. They are detected and the microphone works, but the problem is that the headphones don't produce any sound, although Ubuntu indicates that sound is being emitted. I've tried multiple headphones and I've been trying to fix this issue for the past week, but nothing I've found online has worked. It's worth noting that on my other SSD with Windows, the audio output works correctly there.

I am attaching screenshots of commands and configuration in case anyone has had similar problems.

uname -a

```
Linux diegomazariegos-Strix-15-GL503GE 6.2.0-37-generic #38~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Nov  2 18:01:13 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

sudo lspci | grep Audio:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
```

sudo lshw:

```
*-multimedia
     description: Dispositivo de audio
     producto: Cannon Lake PCH cAVS
     fabricante: Intel Corporation
     id físico: 1f.3
     información del bus: pci@0000:00:1f.3
     nombre lógico: card0
     nombre lógico: /dev/snd/controlC0
     nombre lógico: /dev/snd/hwC0D0
     nombre lógico: /dev/snd/hwC0D2
     nombre lógico: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c
     nombre lógico: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
     nombre lógico: /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
     nombre lógico: /dev/snd/pcmC0D7p
     nombre lógico: /dev/snd/pcmC0D8p
     versión: 10
     anchura: 64 bits
     reloj: 33MHz
     capacidades: pm msi bus_master cap_list
     configuración: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
     recursos: irq:153 memoria:a4518000-a451bfff memoria:a4100000-a41fffff
   *-input:0
        producto: HDA Intel PCH Headset Mic
        id físico: 0
        nombre lógico: input22
        nombre lógico: /dev/input/event14
   *-input:1
        producto: HDA Intel PCH Headphone
        id físico: 1
        nombre lógico: input23
        nombre lógico: /dev/input/event15
   *-input:2
        producto: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3
        id físico: 2
        nombre lógico: input24
        nombre lógico: /dev/input/event16
   *-input:3
        producto: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7
        id físico: 3
        nombre lógico: input25
        nombre lógico: /dev/input/event17
   *-input:4
        producto: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8
        id físico: 4
        nombre lógico: input26
        nombre lógico: /dev/input/event18
```

I attach more useful information:

[option Speaker-Audio yes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tn78.png)

[option headphones-Input Jack-Audio No](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OP9C.png)

[Jack Retasking app part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UjfK.png)
[Jack Retasking app part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5Bpm.png)

I have already tried solutions like these but it hasn't worked for me:

[My microphone is not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897437/my-microphone-is-not-working/1163677#1163677)

https://devicetests.com/install-updated-intel-hda-sound-drivers-ubuntu

https://vidatecno.net/como-solucionar-el-problema-de-falta-de-sonido-en-ubuntu/

https://www.solvetic.com/tutoriales/article/5366-como-solucionar-error-sin-sonido-ubuntu-linux-mint/#google_vignette

Thank you once again for all the support and for making this forum such an amazing community.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved. I tried everything, but by forcing a dependency installation, these were installed today. A software update notification arrived, and upon checking, one of the updates was for the kernel and something related to linux-headers-oem-22.04. I'm sharing the complete log for error correction in case it's helpful to someone.

Start-Date: 2023-12-05  10:38:43
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.166'
Install: linux-modules-6.1.0-1027-oem:amd64 (6.1.0-1027.27, automatic), linux-headers-6.1.0-1027-oem:amd64 (6.1.0-1027.27, automatic), linux-oem-6.1-headers-6.1.0-1027:amd64 (6.1.0-1027.27, automatic), linux-image-6.1.0-1027-oem:amd64 (6.1.0-1027.27, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-image-oem-22.04c:amd64 (6.1.0.1026.27, 6.1.0.1027.28), linux-oem-22.04a:amd64 (6.1.0.1026.27, 6.1.0.1027.28), linux-oem-22.04c:amd64 (6.1.0.1026.27, 6.1.0.1027.28), libfreerdp2-2:amd64 (2.6.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu2.5, 2.9.0+git202211161406-0+remmina202212021510.rfa8e1b1c7.d4b199d2d2~ubuntu22.04.1), libwinpr2-2:amd64 (2.6.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu2.5, 2.9.0+git202211161406-0+remmina202212021510.rfa8e1b1c7.d4b199d2d2~ubuntu22.04.1), libfreerdp-server2-2:amd64 (2.6.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu2.5, 2.9.0+git202211161406-0+remmina202212021510.rfa8e1b1c7.d4b199d2d2~ubuntu22.04.1), linux-headers-oem-22.04c:amd64 (6.1.0.1026.27, 6.1.0.1027.28), libfreerdp-client2-2:amd64 (2.6.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu2.5, 2.9.0+git202211161406-0+remmina202212021510.rfa8e1b1c7.d4b199d2d2~ubuntu22.04.1)
Remove: linux-headers-6.1.0-1026-oem:amd64 (6.1.0-1026.26), linux-oem-6.1-headers-6.1.0-1026:amd64 (6.1.0-1026.26), linux-image-6.1.0-1026-oem:amd64 (6.1.0-1026.26), linux-modules-6.1.0-1026-oem:amd64 (6.1.0-1026.26)
End-Date: 2023-12-05  10:41:00