# Microphone not working on MacBook pro 10.2. with Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Tags: 22.04, microphone, macbook-pro, audio-jack, audio-recording

I have recently installed Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on my MacBook pro 10.02 and noticed that the microphone is not working. It does not matter if I try to use the built-in (internal) microphone, or if I plug in a headset (jack), or use a bluetooth headset. The sound settings give me the option to select given microphone as input, however the selected microphone does not work. I have spent quite some time googling and looking for a solution but nothing so far worked.

**Symptoms:**

Microphone does not detect any sound. It does not matter what microphone I try to use (internal, headset..).

**Here is, what I tried:**

1. Checking the Sound Settings in Ubuntu and making sure the input device is selected and not muted.
2. Adding `options snd-hda-intel model=mbp102` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
3. Making sure that "Analog Stereo Duplex" is selected in `pavucontrol` (configuration panel).
4. Using `alsamixer` and increasing the microphone's gain
5. Connecting unconnected pins using `hdajackretask` as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897437/my-microphone-is-not-working/1163677#1163677)
6. Reinstalling `pulseaudio`
7. Booting into different live ubuntu distros (18.04, and 22.04) - the issue prevails.

**System info:**

`sudo aplay -l`

```
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CS4206 Analog [CS4206 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: CS4206 Digital [CS4206 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`sudo lshw -class multimedia`

```
       description: Video
       product: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
       vendor: Apple Inc.
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@2:1.1
       version: 80.25
       serial: CC2D3L0LGDDN9KB0
       capabilities: usb-2.00
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1b
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
       logical name: card0
       logical name: /dev/snd/controlC0
       logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D0
       logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D3
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D1p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D7p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D8p
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:53 memory:a0610000-a0613fff`
```

`lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

`lspci | grep -i audio`

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
```

Any ideas or advice on what else I might try are more than welcome and highly appreciated! I am also happy to share any further details if necessary.